# How to Get the Time When IIS Started With Classic ASP?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

How to Get the Time When IIS Started With Classic ASP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
' This works on my machine... '
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, procs, proc, creationDate
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 

Set procs = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process where name='inetinfo.exe'")

For Each proc In procs
  creationDate = creationDate & vbCr & proc.CreationDate
Next
```

Comment: Seems to throw "error '80041003'" on my machine unless I disable anonymous access in IIS for the ASP page that executes the above script.

Comment: Sounds like the user that your ASP application runs as does not have enough privileges, maybe temporarily impersonating another user could help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248187